# Prove these equations have only zero solution.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-analysis

> **Original problem**: consider the function $f = f_{a,b,c}(u,v,w)$:
> $$
> f_{a,b,c}(u,v,w) = (v + T)^3 + v T (v+ T) - u^2 T - v w^2, \quad u,v,w \in\mathbb{R},
> $$
> where
> $$
> T = -a u -b v- c w,
> $$
> and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ are three parameters. I want to show that for any (possible) critical point $(u_0,v_0,w_0)$ of $f$, that is,
> $$
> \nabla_{(u,v,w)}f(u_0,v_0,w_0) =0.
> $$
> We have  $$\mbox{rank}\,\nabla^2 f(u_0,v_0,w_0)\ge 2,$$
> here $\nabla^2 f$ is the Hessian of $f$. Therefore, the stationary equation is $\nabla_{(u,v,w)}f(u_0,v_0,w_0) =0$, which is exactly the following three equations I posted. My plan was to show that there is only one the critical point $(0,0,0)$, but it seems not... so the relation on the Hessian should also be taken into account, and suppose on the contrary that rank$\nabla^2 f(u_0,v_0,w_0)$=1, then all $2\times 2 $ submatrix are degenerate. We shall get , actually, $\ge$ 6 equations. Then a tedious computation may be involved to show that all these equations do not have common solutions.

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ be three parameters satisfying
$$abc\ne 0,\quad \mbox{and} \quad 2a^2\ne b^2.$$

Consider the following equations of $(u,v,w)\in\mathbb{R}^3$:

$$
(-c) \bigg(3(v+T)^2-2vT-(u^2+v^2)\bigg) = 2vw,
$$

$$
(-b) \bigg(3(v+T)^2-2vT-(u^2+v^2)\bigg) = T^2 +w^2 +2vT,
$$

$$
(-a)\bigg(3(v+T)^2-2vT-(u^2+v^2)\bigg) = 2uT,
$$
where $$T= -au-bv-cw.$$

Surprisingly, computer (WolframAlpha) tells me that for any $(a,b,c)$ as above, the solution of these equations is
$$
(u,v,w)= (0,0,0).
$$
[image]

How can I prove this claim? I tried many times but fail...

I notice that these equations are equivalent to

$$
3(v+T)^2-2vT-(u^2+v^2) = \frac{2vw}{-c} = \frac{T^2+w^2+2vT}{-b} = \frac{2uT}{-a},
$$
which gives that (if $u\ne 0$ )
$$
T = \frac{a}{c}\frac{vw}{u}.
$$

Another observation is that, if $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\ne (0,0,0)$ is a solution, then for any $t\ne 0$, $(tx_0,ty_0,tz_0)$ is a solution.

Comment: When you're equating the values of $3(v+T)^2-2vT-(u^2+v^2)$ the part divided by $(-b)$ is different from the original equations. Please correct that

Comment: @Gwen Thanks, my fault.

Comment: 3 real "solution "? What does this mean? Like for any a,b,c we get u=0,v=0,w=0? Please clarify

Comment: for any (a,b,c), we get (u,v,w)=(0,0,0) from these equations, see also the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Okay see I reached a point.
$$ \frac{T^2 + w^2 + 2vT}{-b}=\frac{2uT}{-a}$$
or
$$ T^2 + w^2 + 2T(v-\frac{ub}{a})=0$$
Applying the quadratic eqn formula w.r.t $T$, we get
$$T=-(v-\frac{ub}{a}) ± \sqrt {(v-\frac{ub}{a}) ^2 - w^2}$$
Now putting the value of $T=\frac{avw}{cu}$,
$$\frac{avw}{cu} + (v-\frac{ub}{a})=±\sqrt{(v-\frac{ub}{a})^2 - w^2}$$
Squaring both sides, and further simplification gives that:-
$$ (\frac{avw}{cu})^2+ 2\frac{avw}{cu}(v-\frac{ub}{a})=-w^2...(i)$$
From the above equation, $w$ can be taken common and be proved as $w=0$. It's a possible way.  This means that $T=0$ as well. Further values can be computed from here. If $T=0$, then
$$(-a)\bigg(3(v+T)^2-2vT-(u^2+v^2)\bigg) = 2uT \implies 2v^2-u^2=0$$ Here, they can have any value such that $$u=±\sqrt{2}v$$
I've come upto this point. Here $u$ and $v$ does satisfy $u=v=0$, but other values are possible too

If $w≠0$:- (**2nd edit**)

From my previous equation $(i)$, we can also say

$$ (\frac{av}{cu})^2w+ 2\frac{av}{cu}(v-\frac{ub}{a})=-w$$
After rearranging and simplifying this, we get $$w=\frac{2cu(vub-av^2)}{(av)^2+(cu)^2}$$
So if $a=b=c$, $$w=\frac{2u(vu-v^2)}{v^2+u^2}$$
So it's independent of $a,b,c$. For example, in this case, if you take $u=1,v=2$, you get $w=\frac{-4}{5}$.